# How to make emacsclient find the emacs daemon it is executed from

Tags: unix, shell, emacs

I'm trying to move most of my editing and shell activities into emacs, so that I can easily continue my workflow from different computers. I also have different emacs instances for my different projects. E.g., I start up:

```
emacs --daemon=project1
emacs --daemon=project2
```

Then whenever I want to start a frame to work on project1, I do:

```
emacsclient -s project1 -c
```

Mostly it works great, but I have trouble with executing tools from my emacs shells that are trying to fire up an editor using $EDITOR. Of course, what I would want in this case is that a new buffer opens in my current emacs instance, exactly what emacsclient is designed for. So if in a shell buffer in project1's emacs I say:

```
export EDITOR='emacsclient -s project1'
```

then in *that particular* shell everything works perfectly.

My question is, how could I automatically set the EDITOR variable in a way that it points to the emacs instance the current shell is running in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (comint-send-string 
         (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
         (concat "export EDITOR='emacsclient -s " 
             (daemonp)
             " -c'\n"))))
```